# C++ Templates specialisation char* and Valgrind

Tags: c++, templates, memory-leaks, char, valgrind

I've got a huge problem with memory leaks in my program.
I use Valgrind to check memory leaks and with some changes I got about ~20 errors or ~40 errors, but still I can't eliminate all and don't know how.
And I can't change the code in main function, I must fit to it.
I can't change specialisation to string! 
Question is what is a properly way to manage with char* and memory.

Rules:

1. Main code is unchangable
2. Don't pack char* in any smart pointers or other types.

Problem

Managing memory with char* with containers.

Is it still possible ? 
Or instead of container safer is normally allocated array ?

What is wrong with my destructor for char* ?

My main function:

```html
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
char * cpt[]={"tab","tab2","tab3"};
test<char*> test1;
test1.addItem(cpt[1]);
char * item=test1.getItem(0);
item[0]='Z';
cout<<item<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

test.h

```html
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
template<class T>
class test
{
 public:
   ~test();
  void addItem(T element){
  elements.push_back(element);
  }
  T getItem(int i){
  return elements[i];
  }

  vector<T> elements;
};

#endif // TEST_H
```

test.cpp

```html
#include "test.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

template<>
char * test<char*>::getItem(int i)
{
  /*char *nowy=new char(strlen(elements[i])+1);
  //strcpy(nowy,elements[i]);
  return nowy;
  //with above code 39 errorr in Valgrind
  */
  return elements[i]; // with this instead of above 19 errors in Valgrind
  }
  template<>
void test<char*>::addItem(char* element){
  char * c= new char( strlen (element)+1);
  strcpy(c,element);
  elements.push_back(c);
  }
  template<>

 test<char*>:: ~test(){
 for( auto v: elements)
 delete []v; //with this 20 errors
 //delete v; instead of above line 19 errors;
 }
```

Comment: Sorry to have to say it, but being entirely honest, this code is enough of a mess that you shouldn't be changing any of it--you should be throwing it out and starting over. I'm not sure exactly what reasons you think you have for retaining `main` or avoiding `string`, but if you *really* have to use something other than `string`, you should still write your own string class that manages memory sanely, then create a vector of those.

Comment: The point is I can't change the inside of main, but please point out any bugs in.  And the next rule is not to use any kind of smart pointers.

Comment: Sorry, but no. The real point is that you shouldn't be *changing* `main`; you should be throwing it away and starting over.

Comment: The problem is that the templates get messy when T can resolve to a pointer or a non-pointer type, which is the problem you have. You should modify your template to also take in a deleter like [unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) does, but since you cannot change main, it looks like your test class will need to assume that T is a pointer type and in its destructor call `delete[]` on each element.

Comment: Ok i forgot to delete my for .  Main file is out of my range. I can only include files. So what's wrong with my specialised destructor for char* ?

Comment: `main` is invalid C++, as there is missing `const` for the `const` literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace

```
new char(strlen (element) + 1); // this allocate one char with given initial value
```

by

```
new char[strlen (element) + 1]; // array of (uninitialized) char
```

to allocate array of char.

then you have to call `delete []`.